# How do I get a random unused port in ansible

Tags: linux, networking, ansible, port

I want to get a random unused port so that I can `wait_for` it. Preferably in the range of dynamic ports but, at this point, I'm not picky. I'm using Linux and this does not have to be compatible with windows or Mac.

While this question is marked as answered, if anyone has a way to do this simpler and with less calls to shell, post it below. I don't care if this question is four years old.

Comment: Should that port get available at some time, or do you want to `wait_for` it forever?

Comment: I'm want to wait for a ping from a raspberry pi so I know its ready.

Comment: But `wait_for` will wait until something is listening on that port. You will to `wait_for` a port to become available, so you know a server started up. E.g. you install and start a database and then `wait_for` the port. You need to open a port and then wait for the ping to come.

Comment: Oh okay. Cool thanks. I still need a random port though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you do not want to `wait_for` a port, but open one and wait for a ping.
I don't know a simple way to get a random port, so I wrote a little shell script to find one:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: find port
      shell: |
        PORT=5000
        while true; do 
          ss -tulpen | grep ":${PORT}" &> /dev/null
          if [[ "$?" == "1" ]]; then 
            echo "${PORT}"
            exit
          fi
          ((PORT++)) 
        done
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
      register: port
    - name: print port
      debug:
        msg: "{{ port.stdout }}"
    - name: wait for ping
      shell: nc -l "{{ port.stdout }}"
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "Ping received"
```

This looks for a port, prints it to you and then opens the port and waits for a ping using `netcat`. When the ping is received, it prints a message.
Tested this on a ubuntu. You might need different arguments for `netcat` (or here it is `nc`) as different distros ship different version.

EDIT:
After sending the ping to the port, you need to close the TCP connection, because `netcat` will only exit, after the connection is closed.